# How to update/refresh overlays in GMap?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I have this problem:

I have a list of points `List<PointLatLng>` and an overlay where a trajectory of the points is shown. I also use `TabPages` and inside one page there is the `gMapcontrol`. Unfortunately the trajectory is updated only when the page is not shown, I mean, when the focus is on another page.

Once I open the page with the Map the trajectory stops to update. How can I fix this?

I tried with:

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(() => gMapControl.Refresh()));
```

Inside the `DataReceived` event, but it only works as I said before.

Comment: how did you add your `PointLatLng` to the map? Are they markers?

Comment: How about refreshing the 'gMapControl' inside `TabPage.GotFocus()` ?

Comment: Try to set the overlay visibility to false then set it back to true, it will force the map to redraw.

Comment: Ahmed's comment should be set as a real answer. This worked perfectly for my situation and there isn't even a flicker. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem with:

```
gMapControl1.Zoom = -5;
gMapControl1.Zoom = 5;
```